# Нет доступа в интернет из android приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

Пытаюсь сделать запрос при помощи OkHttp в android приложении

```
try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .method("POST", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                        String.format(JSON_LOGIN_TEMPLATE,
                                editTextLogin.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString())))
                .url("https://localhost:8085/users/login")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.code() == 200) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

но оно постаенно крашится. В манифесте добивил разрешения на доступ в интернет, но не помогает.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Пытался проверить разрешение при помощи

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(view.getContext(), "INTERNET");
```

постоянно возвращает -1. Получается, что запрос на использование интернета в манифесте просто игнорируется

Исключение из логов:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.easyteam.easycity, PID: 25244
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
    at com.easyteam.easycity.activity.MainActivity.onButtonClickLogin(MainActivity.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Если крашится , то в логах написано почему.

Comment: Крашится, потому-что разрешение не выдается. В этом вопрос и заключается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в ошибке все написано `NetworkOnMainThreadException` Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь сделать запрос из главного потока.

Оберните ваш код в `AsyncTask` или хотя бы в отдельный поток `Thread`

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      //do time consuming operations
      });
    } 
}).start();
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло